# Putting constraints on parameters of a parametric function in GNUPLOT

Tags: constraints, gnuplot

I am trying to fit a model to some data. everything is OK so far. However I would like to apply some constraints on the parameters of my equation. For example suppose the following function: `f(x)=a*sin(x)+b*cos(x*a/b)`. Suppose "a" and "b" are parameters; and suppose that you wanna fit this equation to some data and that the estimated value of "a" and "b" has to fall in specific different intervals. For example suppose the constraints: a >= 2.0 
and 0.1 < b <= 1.0 
So how can I tell to gnuplot to fit by taking into account the above constraints on the parameters "a" and "b"?

Since I wanna execute the fitting for thousands of curves. I would like to know if there is such a thing similar to an implicit do loop in Fortran; meaning execute the fitting on the data file containing all the curves one after the other?

Your help will be so much appreciated.

Comment: The method in this page might be useful for some cases... http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.jp/2009/12/restricting-fit-parameters.html

Comment: Thanks **roygvib 14 ** , I tried some of those.

Finally I noticed that trying to do the  fitting with the parameters which are not interdependent does somehow help to keep the output parameters (estimated through NLLS fitting) within the desired interval I wanted them to be. This was part of the suggestion of  Karl. 
It does work so far.  And I cant explain how really. 

I think if the parameter constraint was comprehensively implemented in GNUPLOT it would really be great =>> another big blow.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting the fit range is not possible. You could modify the function using the ternary operator (e.g. 'a>2?a:1e300'), but there is a high possibility that your fit becomes unstable, and it is really bad style. ;)

Try to predict your parameters as well as possible to keep them from straying in forbidden regions. Fit the parameters seperately in the beginning, e.g. introduce one of them in a simpler function, only use a small part of the data where part of the parameters is irrelevant, etc. Only in the last step fit your full function with all parameters and the whole dataset.

And gnuplot does have `do for [] {}` and `while () {}` loops that you can use to iterate over your dataset. Before you ask: Array variables to save the fit parameters were only recently intruduced in the development version 5.1.

Comment: Hi **Karl** Really thanks for this hint. I had a hard time trying to find a proper way to do this. 

I am gonna proceed and try it out.  

Sincerely !!

Answer (score 1):

In general, to achieve parameter constraint you can use change of variables. For example to have `a >= amin` you can replace it with

```
a = amin + aa^2
```

where `-inf < aa < +inf` is your new fit parameter. Or, to have `bmin < b <= bmax` you can define

```
b = bmin + (bmax - bmin)/(1 + bb^2)
```

where, again, `bb` is your new fit parameter without constraint.

Using your examples, to have `a >= 2.0` define

```
a = 2.0 + aa^2
```

and to get `0.1 < b <= 1.0` define

```
b = 0.1 + 0.9/(1+bb^2)
```

There are probably an infinite number of ways you can define the change of variables; you should choose a reliable and computationally efficient form. It will also depend on where you want your function to vary rapidly or have asymptotic behavior. For example, the form I used above for `b` approaches `bmin` as `bb` approaches `+inf`. This means that if the target value of `b` is very close to `bmin`, then `bb` has to get very large and the fit procedure may fail. In this case, an alternative form might be more useful, such as:

```
b = bmax - (bmax - bmin) /(1 + bb^2)
```

Another interesting and common category of functions are exponentials. Suppose your fit function is `f(x) = a*exp(-b*(x-c)^2)` and you want to ensure `b > 0` and `a > 0`. It will be more natural to just rewrite:

```
f(x) = exp(aa - (bb*(x-c))^2)
```

Then use the resulting `aa` and `bb` to compute `a = exp(aa)` and `b = bb^2`.

Notice that with this method in general, the uncertainty estimate in `aa` (or `bb`) has to be properly propagated to `a` (or `b`). But that's another topic.